# Custom validation not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: validation, date, laravel-5.4

Working on a Laravel application whereby am working on the backend validation of two dates. The 2 dates are mainly departureDate and returnDate respectively.

On the departure date am trying to validate it to be required, should be of type date and should be a date after today. On the return date I am also trying to implement a validation logic whereby return date should be 3 days or more after departure date but it should be less than 180 days after departure date.

**Validate function**

```
 public function validateDates(Request $request){   
        //dd($request->all());
     $now = new \DateTime();

    $after_date = $now->parse($this->departureDate)->addDays(3);
    $maxdays = $now->parse($this->departureDate)->addDays(180);

        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
          'departureDate' => 'required|date|after:now',
          'returnDate' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:' . $after_date->toDateString().'|before:' . $maxdays->toDateString()
        ], 
        [
            'departureDate.after' => 'Your departure date should be tomorrow or any date in the future',
           'returnDate.after' => 'Your return date should be 3 or more days after the departure date',
           'returnDate.before' => 'Your return date should be no more than 180 days from the departure date',
        ]
    };
```

Comment: Any error being thrown?

Comment: @Mozammil  I get the following error **Call to undefined method DateTime::parse()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic is fine. You are, however, probably looking to use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instead. It has the `parse()` method you are looking for. Also `addDays()` and `toDateString()`.

So, on top of your file, add the following statement:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

and then change your `validateDate()` method to this one:

```
public function validateDates(Request $request)
{   
    $after_date = Carbon::parse($this->departureDate)->addDays(3)->toDateString();
    $max_days   = Carbon::parse($this->departureDate)->addDays(180)->toDateString();

    $validation = $this->validate($request, 
        [
            'departureDate' => 'required|date|after:now',
            'returnDate'    => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:' . $after_date . '|before:' . $max_days
        ], 
        [
            'departureDate.after' => 'Your departure date should be tomorrow or any date in the future',
            'returnDate.after'    => 'Your return date should be 3 or more days after the departure date',
            'returnDate.before'   => 'Your return date should be no more than 180 days from the departure date',
        ]
    );
};
```

I am assuming that you have your departureDate defined somewhere and hence you are using `$this->departureDate`, but if it's coming from your request instead, you should change that to `$request->departureDate` for example.